# How to activate or use the dictionary lens?

Tags: 12.04, lenses, dictionary

I've installed dictionary lens package from Precise PPA. But I don't see a dictionary icon at the bottom of the Dash. I see the package installed in Synaptic,  but how to activate or use the dictionary lens? Yes, I've logged out an back in, even more, I've restarted the computer, but no luck so far. Can someone advise?

Has anyone installed dictionary lens on clean 12.04 install? Does it work for you?

Comment: Link for the lens? After a log out you should have seen the icon in the dash

Comment: used the following but no luck even after log off : http://news.softpedia.com/news/Introducing-Ubuntu-Dictionary-Lens-for-Unity-257011.shtml

Comment: Hi Milen. I too have installed the Lens and there is nothing appearing in my Dash. I've also looked under the `/usr/share/unity/lenses/` which contains all of the lenses installed, but it is not found in the directory. But, according to Synaptic, it is installed. So, I can confirm that it does not seem to work currently on 12.04

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).